# Como filtrar uma lista usando o mesmo parâmetro com dois valores diferentes?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou implementando um **filtro de movimentações** onde você pode escolher o parâmetro em que o filtro deve se basear (por exemplo: Data, Espécie, Usuário) e ao escolher qualquer um desses parâmetros, é possível escolher o valor dele em uma lista (com valores do banco de dados).

A questão é que esses **inputs** podem receber múltiplos valores, mas ele considera somente um destes valores...

Exemplo:

```
/consultas/movimentacao-residuo?cd_especie=1&cd_especie=2
```

Neste exemplo ele irá considerar o primeiro parâmetro, mas o segundo não.

Qual seria a solução para isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando o mesmo campo várias vezes para receber valores diferentes. Uma forma de resolver isso é utilizar apenas um campo recebendo todos os valores separados por algum caractere.

Por exemplo:

```
// Nesse exemplo utilizo a virgula como separador 
/consultas/movimentacao-residuo?cd_especie=1,2,3
```

Na função que você vai receber os valores você faz o seguinte tratamento.

```
public function filtrarMovimentacoes( Request $request ) 
{
    // Você vai ter um array de IDS
    $cd_especie = explode( ',', $request->input('cd_especie') ); 

    // Agora é só utilizar para filtrar o que você quiser
    // whereIn recebe como segundo parâmetro um array
    DB::table('movimentacoes')
                ->whereIn('cd_especie', $cd_especie) 
                ->get();

}
```

Comment: Obrigado @kayo-bruno, resolvi com esta mesma ideia só que de forma diferente!